# HIVE JSON INPUT - should the JSON be in one line

Tags: json, hive, cloudera

I am trying to load a JSON data to a HIVE table. 
I was wondering should the JSON be in one single line only . I have tested this way with this data formatted like this:

```
"associatedDrug": {"name":"asprin", "dose":"","strength":"500 mg"}
"associatedDrug": {"name":"asprin2", "dose":"","strength2":"500 mg"}
```

or it can be provided in a formatted format like this:

```
"associatedDrug": {
                "name":"asprin",
                "dose":"",
                "strength":"500 mg"
          }
```

And if it formatted should is there a SERDE PROPERTIES that I can include so that it knows the RECORD END OF LINE is ???

Comment: The common JSON SerDe does not support multi-lines documents

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz.. thanks for the feedback